# IO_Error opening file using Adobe Air App on a Mac

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I have an Adobe Air Application that would open an csv file on Mac. I am getting an error which I am not getting with the same app for Windows, so I am thinking something about file locations, etc is amiss. Here is the code:

```
var file: File = File.applicationStorageDirectory;

file = file.resolvePath("A&P plans");

file.addEventListener(FileListEvent.SELECT_MULTIPLE, filesSelected);

function filesSelected(event: FileListEvent): void {
  
   //trace(event.files.length);
 
   fileList = new Array();
   fileNames = new Array();
      
   for (var i: uint = 0; i < event.files.length; i++) {
        fileList.push(event.files[i].nativePath);
        trace("name of file loaded is ", event.files[i].name, "where :", event.files[i].nativePath);
   }
}

var urlRequest: URLRequest = new URLRequest(fileList[0]);

function openCSVFile():void{

  csv = new CSV(urlRequest);
  csv.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onComplete);
  csv.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onErrorOpening);

  function onComplete(event:Event):void{
     trace("file open successful");
  }

  function onErrorOpening(event:IOErrorEvent):void{
    trace ("error opening file");
  }
}
```

The URLRequest trace shows the location where it should be, so the app knows where to look, and it does find the file. Here is the result of the trace :/Applications/myApp.app/Contents/Resources/A&P plans/majors/NationalLeague.csv. Yet, instead of the completeEvent showing the trace, the errorEvent is inovked. Any ideas where to look for the issue? The file does not have any weird characters in its name or anything. Tracing the error shows the following: Error #2032: Stream Error. Thanks

Comment: Try using **event.files[i].url** rather than **event.files[i].nativePath**. Also, you form you **URLRequest** instance **BEFORE** the select dialog gives you any result, which is obviously wrong. Also, don't define functions inside functions.

Comment: @Organis Agreed, but those were put for illustration of the problem I am having. Thanks for the feedback. Replacing event.files[i].nativePath with event.files[i].url did the trick. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Quite possibly the ampersand and the space in 'A&P plans' might be troublesome.

Try removing/changing those.

Comment: Thank you so much. I removed those anyway for good measure. Replacing nativePath with url did the trick